# Problems installing Torch for R for Mac arm64

Tags: r, rstudio, torch

I'm using the Macbook Pro with the M1 chip. I have recently installed the R for the arm64 architecture from this [link](https://utstat.toronto.edu/cran/) (R-4.1.0-arm64.pkg) and the RStudio from the daily builds (version 1.5.194).

With this installation, I was able to install almost all libraries in R and also to connect the tensorflow from a python installation (I followed these [instructions](http://imachordata.com/2021/05/07/r-tensorflow-on-an-m1-mac-without-crashing/)).

Now I tried to install the [Torch](https://torch.mlverse.org/) library for R (using the command `install_torch()` after installing the package from CRAN) and I'm having the following error:

```
Error in cpp_lantern_init(install_path()) : 
  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib - dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/torch/deps/liblantern.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Did anyone have this problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: The M1 installation is not currently supported. You can subscribe to this issue https://github.com/mlverse/torch/issues/595 for more information.

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait for the M1 support, then...

Thanks a lot for the link.